# managing redirection with google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I have a site that contains the file

```
redirect.php?id=123
```

It redirects folks to another site using an `id` it pulls from the database.
I'd like to track the page on Google Analytics, see where users are coming from, and what popular sites they're going to.. etc.
I currently set up the page so that it pulls (with PHP) the link from the database, and outputs the `ga.js` stuff and a javascript redirect.

The issue is that I'm getting the data on my analytics dashboard as if every `id` is a different page..

What is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for pages of the type `redirect.php?id=x` then the page Carlos links to is how you would do it.

You would want to exclude the `id` parameter from your search.  Then Analytics would combine all the `redirect.php?id=1` `redirect.php?id=2` `redirect.php?id=3` pages as just a single page named `redirect.php`

[How do I exclude query parameters from my reports?](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55499)